# Android 10 adb shell input keyevent returns 0

Tags: input, mocking, adb, keyevent

I'm trying to use ADB shell input keyevent 1000 to test my custom hardware device in android 10, but it returns 0 in ADB log. 
 Secondly, I found ADB shell input keyevent 288 returns keycode 288, ADB shell input keyevent 289 returns 0. and the max keycode in original KeyEvent.java is 288.

How could I use ADB shell input keyevent 1000 return 1000 in android 10?

Answer (score 0):

05-07 04:03:50.360 1271 1514 D InputDispatcher: Setting input event injection result to 0. injectorPid=6874, injectorUid=2000
05-07 04:03:50.361 1271 4338 D InputDispatcher: injectInputEvent - Waiting for 1 pending foreground dispatches.
05-07 04:03:50.365 3187 3187 D ViewRootImpl: processKeyEvent oldKeycode: 0 and newKeycode: 0
05-07 04:03:50.368 1271 4338 D InputDispatcher: injectInputEvent - Finished with result 0. injectorPid=6874, injectorUid=2000

when you input key > 288 will return 0, see InputReader.cpp:

if (getEventHub()->mapKey(getDeviceId(), scanCode, usageCode, mMetaState, &keyCode, &keyMetaState, &policyFlags)) {

keyCode = AKEYCODE_UNKNOWN;

keyMetaState = mMetaState;

policyFlags = 0;

}

if you could not get the mapkey, it will return AKEYCODE_UNKNOWN.